# How do I restrict chrome greasemonkey scripts to a single webpage, or just certain webpages?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, greasemonkey

Is there a way to prevent chrome from running greasemonkey scripts except for on certain domains? I could do some hackery with `location.href`, but it would be nice if there were a cleaner solution.

When I install by dragger `script.user.js` into the browser, the script automatically runs for *all* websites.

How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use `@match`, as described [here](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts).

Example:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @match http://*/*
// @match http://*.google.com/*
// @match http://www.google.com/*
// @match https://www.google.com/*
// ==/UserScript==
```

Comment: That’s whole domains. How can it be restricted to a single page?

Comment: Don't forget to add the `https` ones too.

Answer (score 4):

using @include @exclude tags in metadata?
<strike>http://diveintogreasemonkey.org/helloworld/metadata.html</strike>
https://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block

Comment: Is this link broken?